# "Don't judge a man until you've walked a mile in his shoes"

Tags: translation, set-phrases, phrase-requests, proverbs

What is the Japanese equivalent of "Don't judge a man until you've walked a mile in his shoes"?

Comment: 身になる
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210689/meaning/m0u/ Perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I think the literal translation of it is "彼の立場になってみるまで、彼を判断するな", but it isn't a proverb.

わが身をつねって人の痛さを知れ(Pinch yourself to know the pain others feel when they are pinched), which is a proverb, would be close to it.

Comment: >わが身をつねって人の痛さを知れ よく考えましたね。似てるようで違うような。違うようで似ているような。近似度75%位ですか。

Comment: すいません。インターネットで検索しました。

Comment: 近似度を変えました。オリジナルで諺｛ことわざ｝をつくりませんか。

Comment: What is the "literal translation" in roomaji?

Comment: I think 彼の靴を履いて一マイル歩くまでは、彼を判断するな.